# Getting field data within razorview c# code

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a ternary operator within a checkbox field.  I would like to access the value of the field for comparison purposes within the ternary operator.

I have about 50 fields containing this sort of logic, and for each field I have been hard-coding the right hand side of the comparison, and it is always the value of my checkbox, which seems pretty redundant.
E.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Sem1CourseOfferMode" value="Blended" class="enableDisable1" @(Model.Sem1CourseOfferMode.Contains("Blended") ? "checked" : "")>
<input type="checkbox" name="Sem1CourseOfferMode" value="Online" class="enableDisable1" @(Model.Sem1CourseOfferMode.Contains("Online") ? "checked" : "")>
<input type="checkbox" name="Sem1CourseOfferMode" value="Other" class="enableDisable1" @(Model.Sem1CourseOfferMode.Contains("Other") ? "checked" : "")>
```

Ideally, I would like to replace the C# bits with a simple statement as such

```
@(Model.Sem1CourseOfferMode.Contains(this.value) ? "checked" : "")
```

Is it possible for me access the value of the parent wrapping checkbox? Thanks!

Comment: Are those values (Blended, Online, Other) etc, data driven? Ie: you have a `List<string> CourseOfferModes` in your view model?

Comment: No they are not.  They are hard coded in the view

Comment: Is there a reason why? 50 hardcoded fields is a pretty bad idea. If you stuff those in a database, you can include them in your viewmodel, and then iterate through them and use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(...)` and get the functionality you desire with relative ease.

Comment: Oh, these are the max no. of choices for this checkbox group.  The other checkboxes really only have one value (kinda like, "check yes if ..." and then fill in this textbox below.  I didn't want to store all these other value in the db, but I get where you are coming from.

Comment: Personally I would add helper properties to the model. e.g. like `.BlendedCheck`, `.OfflineCheck` etc and have those return the "checked" or blank strings. I generally keep the view as clean as possible to simplify maintenance. In this case, where you want 3 inputs per item, I would create a partial view or Html extension method.